# Communties licenses working concurrently with Partner Portal licenses on Contact

Tags: community, partner-portal

If we have contacts with Partner Portal licenses, can they also have sfdc Communities licenses at the same time

Answer (score 1):

No, external Communities/Portal users have a one-to-one relationship with a contact record. The User object has a single lookup to Contact, which cannot be changed. Moreover, two users can't lookup to the same contact. You would need duplicate contacts and duplicate users for the same person to hold two licenses.

Answer (score 1):

Partner Portal users can be in your community without needing a community license.

We right now have a Partner Community, and we made our existing partner portal users (on their existing partner portal licenses) members of the community.  Technically they can still get to the old portal UI, but they're supposed to go to the community now (enforced with a redirect)

It's more of an "overlay" than an "either or".  You can take customer portal users and make them members of the community, and take internal users and make them members of the community.

Definitely not what I was expecting, where partner portal requires a specific license.  Communities seem to just need "some license" and you say which profiles belong to the community.